# Looking for the same Trader buying and selling the same product within the 3minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below I've the example table

```
    Create Table #A 
(
    Time nvarchar(70),
    Trader nvarchar(30),
    Product nvarchar(30),
    [Buy/Sell] nvarchar(30)
)

Insert into #A Values

('2019-03-01T14:22:29z', 'Jhon', 'Apple', 'Buy'),
('2019-03-01T12:35:09z', 'Jhon', 'Orange', 'Sell'),
('2019-03-01T12:35:09z', 'Mary', 'Milk', 'Buy'),
('2019-03-01T12:35:10z', 'Susan', 'Milk', 'Buy'),
('2019-03-01T12:35:23z', 'Tom', 'Bread', 'Sell'),
('2019-03-01T14:15:52z', 'Jhon', 'Apple', 'Sell'),
('2019-03-01T14:15:53z', 'Tom', 'Orange', 'Sell'),
('2019-03-01T14:22:33z', 'Mary', 'Apple', 'Buy'),
('2019-03-01T14:22:37z', 'Mary', 'Orange', 'Sell'),
('2019-03-01T12:37:41z', 'Susan', 'Milk', 'Buy'),
('2019-03-01T12:37:41z', 'Susan', 'Milk', 'Buy')

Select * from #A
```

Basically I'm to get the same Trader buying and selling the same product within the 3minutes

Below I've tried this but not the correct one and working

```
;With DateTimeTbl
as
(
select SUBSTRING(a.Time,1,10) date, SUBSTRING(a.Time,12,8) Time1, a.*
-- lead(Time) over(order by time) cnt 
from #A a 
),
DataTbl
as
(
Select d.*, row_number() over(Partition by d.Trader,d.product order by d.time1) CntSrs  
from DateTimeTbl d 
--where [buy/sell] = 'Sell'
)
Select lag(Time1) over(order by time) cnt, d.*  from DataTbl d where CntSrs>1
```

Comment: And once again you choose the wrong datatypes for your table. Time should not be a string and certainly not 70 characters. Same problem as your previous question.

Comment: @Piyusha . . . I don't think your data has any examples of what you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah you're right. My example data don't have any perfect records to be in result set.

Comment: @SMor Yeah you're right. But I'm bit confused of this type of datetime format i.e. '2019-03-01T14:22:29z'. That's why I have used varchar for that T and Z. Can you please suggest what'll be the perfect datatype in SQLServer for this. DateTime is not working for this type of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically I'm to get the same Trader buying and selling the same product within the 3minutes

I would suggest `lead()`.  To get the first record:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             lead(time) over (partition by trader, product order by time) as next_time,
             lead(buy_sell) over (partition by trader, product order by time) as next_buy_sell
      from #a a
     ) a
where next_time < dateadd(minute, 3, time) and
      buy_sell <> next_buy_sell;
```

Note:  This assumes that `buy_sell` takes on only two values, which is consistent with your sample data.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e6431716d298afda2d3bfeef5aacd6f0) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that it fixes the data types to be appropriate (for the `time` column) and renames the last column so it does not need to be escaped.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is working absolutely fine.